# Is it possible to turn the camera LED on of a device from the browser?

Tags: webrtc

We are implementing a javascript library that uses the camera of the device on mobile web browsers. It was working well on Android using Chrome and some versions of the default Browser app. Since iOS 11 and Safari 11, we are able to access the camera on iOS too.

I was wondering if we can use this API to turn on the LED flashlight of the device. And in what platforms and browsers would that work.

Comment: I don't know why you think one has anything to do with the other… AFAIK no such API exists.

Comment: Both on Android and iOS SDKs allow access yo the flash light through the camera API. I was just guessing it could be the same for webrtc.

Comment: you can use flashlight as described in this reponse
<p>check this [#37848494](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848494/is-it-possible-to-control-the-camera-light-on-a-phone-via-a-website)