# Turn on / off mobile flashlight from a web browser

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, browser, camera

I know there is a way to turn on front / rear camera but in my case I was wondering if there was a way to toggle on and off the camera flashlight from a web browser.

Comment: Give a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47153547/6313073).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to control the camera light on a phone via a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848494/is-it-possible-to-control-the-camera-light-on-a-phone-via-a-website)

Comment: I have actually tried that solution from angel Politis but nothing happens on my android  phone.

Answer (score 4):

I have found out why the solution suggested by @Angel Politis was not working for me and it has to do  with SSL protected page.
In essence I have visited the other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47153547/6313073) as suggested and copied the script but it did not work when I had upload it to my server which is not using the HTTPS protocol. Howwever, I have tried on a different server, (HTTPS), and it works flawlessly.

Many thanks all.