# In Chrome how to open camera in iOS

Tags: ios, angular, mobile, qr-code, mobile-website

We have a mobile web app based on Angular 5 need to open camera to capture a qr code. 
In Safari is fine, however, we cannot do it with Chrome and Firefox. 
Thanks.

Comment: We have experienced the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Some iOS versions are not support Chrome. 
We have to work around with upload the photo instead of open the camera.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53093348/1439168