# WebRTC getUserMedia() - Does not work on iphone ios chrome

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

I am trying to access the users mobile camera via webrtc `getUserMedia()`.

I am using IOS 12 and chrome 69. However it does not work.

See the below example

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53093348/69683 - this is a known bug in iOS that Apple have shown no interest in fixing