# flash light on react web react-html5-camera-photo

Tags: html, reactjs, camera

I have a web app that is working fine taking photos.

Now I need to let the user take the photo with a flashlight, I am using
[react-html5-camera-photo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5-camera-photo)

[I intend to use the flash like in link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848494/is-it-possible-to-control-the-camera-light-on-a-phone-via-a-website). in mobile device and torch option works for a secure server with SSL certificate

How to accomplish this?