# Anyway can open mobile (for android and IOS) flash by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, mobile

I am doing a video call on the web, and I am trying to open the user's mobile flash when capture photo, is it anyway I can do this in javascript?

The flash I mentioned is the flashlight on mobile devices.

I had tried the media stream track method, but can only work for some devices only. cannot work on the iPhone.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to control the camera light on a phone via a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848494/is-it-possible-to-control-the-camera-light-on-a-phone-via-a-website)

Comment: I had tried this, but only some devices can work, I had checked the capabilities, some devices do not have the torch, so cannot open thier flash.

and some devices cannot turn off the flash after turn on.