# Is it possible to create a web app that can access the torch from safari using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I'm working on a website that's supposed to be able to access the flashlight on both android and IOS. I managed to find a way to turn on the torch from android through chrome ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848494/is-it-possible-to-control-the-camera-light-on-a-phone-via-a-website)) this same code however isn't working on my IOS device, even though the browser is showing that safari is actually accessing camera.

P.S. I'm running on IOS 12.2

Comment: Well as stated in the comments on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47153547/8902440) it isn't working in safari or iOS...

Comment: that was 3 years ago though, thought that things might be different now, but I guess not..  edit: Oh actually the comment you're referring to  is from 2019 and after further research it seems like ImageCapture is definitely not supported on IOS.. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately Apple is actively removing functionality from the browser like torch zoom and music controls in the name of security. You can open this link on any device and it will show you the list of supported constraints for that device https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints#result